# How do I create a 3 second delay in this jQuery?

Tags: jquery

```
jQuery.noConflict();

jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    // milliseconds
    var intervalTime = 75,

    div = jQuery(".animate"), st = div.text(), timer, count = 0, total = st.length;
    div.html("").css("visibility", "visible");

    timer = setInterval(showLetters, intervalTime);

    function showLetters() {

        if(count < total) {

            div.html(div.text().split("_").join("") + st.charAt(count) + "");
            count++;

        }
        else {

            clearInterval(timer);

        }

    }

});
```

---

```
<div class="animate">Some text here.</div>
```

Comment: A three second delay to do what exactly?

Comment: I think to animate `div` content to be visible letter by letter.

Comment: When the page loads I would like it to wait 3 seconds before it displays the text.

Answer (score 3):

To 'wait' to do something in Javascript, you can always use

```
setTimeout(callback, intervalInMillis)
```

So if its `showLetters()` you want to wait 3 seconds to do, you would need

```
setTimeout(showLetters(), 3000);
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Can you be more specific than 'its not working'? *How* is it not working? Always helpful to people to have more information, we're all happy to help here but you need to help us help you. [Help MEE. Help YOUU.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XmlXU4uK5rA)

Comment: Im not sure how much more specific you need it to be to understand?
"When the page loads I would like it to wait 3 seconds before it displays the text"... Which part in that is so hard to understand?
I have already found the answer elsewhere. Thanks

Comment: Okay a couple of things here:
1. Its not that its difficult to understand the behavior you desire, its that when a solution is offered and it doesn't provide the desired behavior, you need to describe the 'observed behavior' so that we know what the disconnect is.
2. When you discover the solution to your own problem that's awesome! However, it is common courtesy on this website to then post what that solution was, for future users to learn from :) 
Glad you found your answer though!